# Compilation error in list while using C++11

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, compiler-errors, noexcept

I get the following error while compiling my C++ code using std=c++11 option.

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/list:63:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qlist.h:51,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/QList:1,

/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_list.h:591:68: error: ‘std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<typename std::__cxx11::_List_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Node_alloc_type>::value’ is not a type
       noexcept(is_nothrow_default_constructible<_Node_alloc_type>::value)
```

The code compiles, if I use std=c++98 option! But I need to compile it using C++11.

Comment: Strange. Is that the very first error and the entire error message?

Comment: You've done something weird. Whatever class is being put into the list can't create the `is_nothrow_default_constructible` template. Since the only things it can do is be true or false that means it's likely the class cannot be constructed at all. We'd definitely need to see more code. And definitely try making a small test program that only includes that one class, not all the Qt junk, and see if it can compile.

Comment: My psychic powers suggest that Qt 4, which was developed between 2005 and up through 2011, isn't C++11 compliant.

Comment: @ZanLynx You were right. I was using SQLiteCpp (https://github.com/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp), an old version "0.9.9". To detect C++11 compiler they had used  #if (defined(__GNUC__) && (__GNUC__ >= 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 7 ) && defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__)), which was not working as expected. I changed it to #if (__cplusplus >= 201103L)  which removed the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As ZanLynx rightly suspected, the error was thrown from some other part of the code.
I was using SQLiteCpp (github.com/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp), an old version "0.9.9". To detect C++11 compiler they had used `#if (defined(GNUC) && (GNUC >= 4 && GNUC_MINOR >= 7 ) && defined(GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X))`, which was not working as expected. I changed it to `#if (__cplusplus >= 201103L)` which removed the error. 
Thank you ZanLynx!